# how to build a python proxy server on google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

I live in China and the Great Firewall blocked Youtube and twitter. So I want to build a proxy server on google appengine in python to bypass that. Does anyone know any open source GAE project on that?
Thx~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try gappproxy http://code.google.com/p/gappproxy/

But since the keyword **gappproxy** is blocked by censors, which means you cannot visit any url containing the keyword in China, you may first find a web proxy like http://4624.info to visit the project homepage.

By the way, you don't have to use those tools to access twitter, there are many twitter proxy websites accessible in China, which are based on twitter APIs. For example, http://rabr.in is a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

please try to use http://proxy202.appspot.com